# SwiftUI find time elapsed between first time and now

Tags: date, swiftui, timer, calendar, compare

I'm trying to do a timer in my app, but to have the ability to continue even if the user kill the app in the multitask I use `@AppStorrage` to store my initial time.
As it is not possible to save a `DATE()` in the `@AppStorrage` I save my initial hours:min into a String.

Then in my Timer function I'd like to compare the initial saved time with the current time using `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: initialTime, to: Date())`

I have this error on this line : `Cannot assign value of type 'DateComponents' to type 'Double'`

The code where I define the `@AppStorage` var :

```
@AppStorage("flightMode_DepTime") private var flightModeDepTime: String = ""
@ObservedObject var timerManager = TimerFunc()
var body: some View {
// ...
   Button {
             isStandbyMode.toggle()
             if !isStandbyMode{
                UserDefaults.standard.set(Date().formatted(.dateTime.hour().minute()), forKey: "flightMode_DepTime")
                timerManager.start() 
             }else{
                timerManager.pause()
             }
           } label: {
             if isStandbyMode{
                 Image(systemName: "timer")
                 Text("STBY MODE ")
             }else{
                 Image(systemName: "airplane")
                 Text("FLIGHT MODE ")
             }
          }
// ... 
}
```

And here is my timer function :

```
@AppStorage("flightMode_DepTime") private var flightModeDepTime: String = ""
    
private var initialTime: Date = Date()
private var now: Date = Date()

func start() {
        mode = .running
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) {timer in
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.timeStyle = .medium
            
            initialTime = formatter.date(from: self.flightModeDepTime) ?? Date()
       
            self.secondsElapsed = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: initialTime, to: now)

        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How about using `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` which is a double and can be stored in `@AppStorage`.

Comment: I've this error : `Cannot convert value of type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double') to expected argument type 'Date'` in addition to the old one !

Comment: Store start time as TimeInterval (aka Double) `startTime = `Date().timeIntervalSince1970`.  When it comes time to compute elapsed time: `elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime`.  Don't store Dates anywhere.

Comment: yeah this way is working fine ! Thanks, I was thinking that Timestamp would have been arrested but in fact not apparently !